# Deploying sveltekit app with Sentry installed on netlify recieves Sentry-CLI error

Tags: sveltekit, netlify, sentry

I have installed Sentry on SvelteKit project, and it worked fine in my local development environment. When I pushed the repository for Netlify deployment, I received the following error when previewing the deployed app:

*"Error - Sentry CLI binary for this platform/architecture not found! It seems like none of the "@sentry/cli" package's optional dependencies got installed. Please make sure your package manager is configured to install optional dependencies."*

I tried to install Sentry-Cli on the development environment (package.json), so it gets installed when it's synchronized and deployed in Netlify. But the same message is still there.

Thank you for your help.

Cheers,